# Non-linear function such that $f(ax)=af(x)$ for every $a \in \mathbb R, x \in \mathbb R^n$

Tags: functions, linear-transformations

> Let $f :  \mathbb R^n \to  \mathbb R^n$ be a function such that
>   $f(ax)=af(x)$ for every $a \in \mathbb R, x \in \mathbb R^n$.
>   Does it follow that $f$ is linear?

I don't think so, if $n>1$. If $n=1$, we have $f(a)=af(1)=\lambda a$ with $\lambda =f(1)$. Otherwise I'm not sure what to do.

Thank you!

Comment: $$f(x_1,x_2)=x_1\cdot\mathbf 1_{x_1x_2>0}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia helps here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map): For linearity, a function needs to satify two conditions:

- **additivity** (this is missing in your excercise):$$f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) + f ( y )$$
- **homogeneity** of degree 1: $$f ( α x ) = α f ( x )$$

Wikipedia has a [nice example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Example_1) of a function with only the second property (The picture on the right side):

$$ f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl} x, & \mbox{if } x \cdot y > 0\\ 0, & \mbox{else} \end{array}\right. $$

You are right for $n=1$, though. Additivity follows from homogeneity then.